# 'NoneType' object is not iterable when list append elements in function call argument list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I tried to append an element to a list in a function call, which accepts a list as argument,

```
def print_options(title, option_list):
    print('\n' + title)
    for index, elem in enumerate(option_list):
        print(index, '-', elem)

options = ['A', 'B', 'C']

print_options('Title', options.append('D'))
```

but this failed with

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

have to do

```
options.append('D')
print_options('Title', options)
```

to resolve the above issue. Wondering why it has to be this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`append` works in place and returns None.
Meaning that the `append()`-function in python does only change the object itself but does not return anything. That is why you can not use it in the funciton call directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> help(list.append)
Help on method_descriptor:

append(...)
    L.append(object) -> None -- append object to end
```

Instead of a `list`, you are passing `None` as an argument.